# How to get this limit for $d \geq 3$?

Tags: combinatorics, limits, combinations

How can we get the limit of the following formula ?$$(2d)^{-2n} \binom{2n}{n}\sum\limits_{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_d=n}(n!/n_1!n_2!\cdots n_d!)^2$$

The limit equals $2(d/4n\pi)^{d/2}$  where $d=1,2, \ldots$

It's for $d=1,2$.

But i can't get it for $d \geq 3$.

[image]

This picture is from [p193](https://zh.1lib.limited/book/498414/be20bf)

Comment: See theorem 4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.5028, which gives precisely the asymptotic for the sum of squares of the multinomial coefficients that shows the limit

Comment: @dua Thank you a lot!